# Why is my attempt to iterate through a list of lists and update dictionary values resulting in unchanged dictionary?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, iteration

I want to iterate through a list of lists and if an instance in the list matches a key in a dictionary, add 1 to that dictionary key value. However, when I execute my code it returns the dictionary with no changes to the values. Thank you for your time & help. I searched for a similar question but did not find one that addressed this issue. My apologies if I missed it.

I have a list of hurricanes and the areas they affected. I have a dictionary with key, value pairs for the uniquely affected area, and the number of times affected (set to zero). I want to iterate through the list of hurricane instances and each time I pass through a location in the dictionary increase the value of the unique area by 1. Currently, with the code I’m running the returned dictionary is unchanged.

I've included smaller examples of material I'm working with:
(test_list is a list of areas affected by a hurricane resulting in a list of lists)

```
test_list = [['Central America', 'Mexico', 'Cuba', 'Florida', 'The Bahamas'], ['Lesser Antilles', 'The Bahamas', 'United States East Coast', 'Atlantic Canada'], ['The Bahamas', 'Northeastern United States'], ['Lesser Antilles', 'Jamaica', 'Cayman Islands', 'Cuba', 'The Bahamas', 'Bermuda']]

test_dict = {
'Central America': 0, 'Mexico': 0, 'Cuba': 0, 'Florida', 0, 'The Bahamas': 0, 'Lesser Antilles': 0, 'United States East Coast', 'Atlantic Canada': 0, 'Northeastern United States': 0, 'Jamaica': 0, 'Cayman Islands': 0, 'Bermuda': 0}
```

**GOAL**

if I performed:

```
area_counted = area_counter(test_list, test_dict)
```

I would have expected:

```
area_counted = {
'Central America': 1, 'Mexico': 1, 'Cuba': 2, 'Florida', 1, 'The Bahamas': 4, 'Lesser Antilles': 2, 'United States East Coast': 1, 'Atlantic Canada': 1, 'Northeastern United States': 1, 'Jamaica': 1, 'Cayman Islands': 1, 'Bermuda': 1}
```

However, this was not my result.

**CODE**

```
def area_count(input_dict, input_list):
  new_dict = {}
  new_dict.update(input_dict)
  for i in list:
      for j in i:
        if j == new_dict[j]:
          new_dict[j] += 1
        else:
          pass
  return new_dict

area_counted = area_count(test_dict, test_list)
print(area_counted)
```

**outputs the following:**

```
area_counted = {
'Central America': 0, 'Mexico': 0, 'Cuba': 0, 'Florida', 0, 'The Bahamas': 0, 'Lesser Antilles': 0, 'United States East Coast', 'Atlantic Canada': 0, 'Northeastern United States': 0, 'Jamaica': 0, 'Cayman Islands': 0, 'Bermuda': 0}
```

edit-1: edited area_count parameters to input_list instead of list, corrected parameter input order for area_counted to match area_count function.

Comment: `if j == new_dict[j]:` will never be true, because `new_dict[j]` will be an `int` like `0`, and `j` will be a string like `'Central America'`

Comment: This is certainly not what you have tried. Your code does not run at all. 1) SyntaxError: invalid syntax, because your dictionary definition does not make a dictionary. 2) you pass the parameters in wrong order

Comment: @ThomasWeller Would you please elaborate more on the dictionary creation issue? I have new_dict = {}, update new_dict, and then return new_dict at the end of the function. What am I missing? Thank you for pointing out my parameter mistake I clearly should have caught that before posting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`new_dict[j]` always is equal to `0` initially  (since in test_dict all the values are 0)

you are comparing it to a string

```
if "Central America" == 0:
    set_to_1()
```

hopefully you can see how this never sets it to 1

I think what you want is

```
if j in new_dict:
    new_dict[j] = 1
```

as an unrelated aside you really should not name a variable `list` as that is a built in entity that you end up shadowing

Comment: Jordan, thank you for your feedback. It helped me see my if statement was comparing the string to the value. Your suggestion, ```if j in new_dict:``` solved the issue for me.